# Find anagrams in pyspark

Tags: python, mapreduce, pyspark

Type of variable `origin` is `pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD`, and `origin` contains something like:

```
[u'masquerade',
 u'squaremade',
 u'dianas',
 u'naiads',
 u'antagonist',
 u'stagnation',
 u'bates',
 u'beast',
 u'beats',
 u'thanks']
```

I want the key and all the anagrams sorted by the key:

```
[(u'aadeemqrsu', {u'masquerade', u'squaremade'}),
(u'aadins', {u'dianas', u'naiads'}),
(u'aaginnostt', {u'antagonist', u'stagnation'}), ...
(u'abest', {u'bates', u'beast', u'beats'}), ...]
```

I know it may need `map` or `reducebykey` function, but I really have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to define an RDD:

```
origin =  [u'masquerade',
    u'squaremade',
    u'dianas',
    u'naiads',
    u'antagonist',
    u'stagnation',
    u'bates',
    u'beast',
    u'beats',
    u'thanks']

origin_rdd = sc.parallelize(origin)
```

you can print it to see the result:

```
print origin_rdd.take(10)
```

Now convert it to key-value pairs:

```
origin_kv = origin_rdd.map(lambda word: ("".join(sorted([letter for letter in word])),[word]))
```

do the reduce:

```
res = origin_kv.reduceByKey(lambda word1,word2: word1 + word2)
```

You can print the result:

```
print res.take(10)
```

If you need also the keys to be sorted, and you have enough space in the driver for all the data, you can sort the result:

```
print sorted(res.take(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the anagram  data like
'PSALM  MEALS  MESAL LEAMS SPALE  PELAS PEALS  SEPAL  MELAS SAMEL PALES  SALEP MALES AMPLE  LEAPS  Pelas'

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("/data/anagram.txt")
```

Create a flat map by removing duplicates words

```
flatMap=rdd.flatMap(lambda s : s.split(" ")).distinct()
```

Create paired rdd with sorted words as key and word as value

```
pairedMap=flatMap.map(lambda word : ("".join(sorted(word.lower())), word))
```

Create dataframe to perform grouping

```
df=pairedMap.toDF()

df=df.groupBy(col("_1").alias("anagram_char")).agg(collect_list(col("_2")).alias("anagram_words"))
```

Checking words pattern that repeats more than one

```
df=df.withColumn("word_count", size((col("anagram_words"))))
df=df.filter(col("word_count") > lit(1))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

output will be like

```
|anagram_Pattern|anagram_word                                            |word_count|
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|aelps          |[SPALE, PALES, SALEP, PELAS, PEALS, SEPAL, LEAPS, Pelas]|8         |
|aelms          |[MEALS, MESAL, MELAS, MALES, LEAMS, SAMEL]              |6         |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```